# Why does datetime.fromtimestamp(time / 1e3) results in java.util.GregorianCalendar?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a Spark job which has a UDF like this:

```
def checkTimeRange(etime):
     date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(etime / 1e3)
     if datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 26, 8, 00, 00) < date < datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 25, 9, 00, 00):
       return True
     else:
        return False
```

I check whether the event time falls within a range and return True or False accordingly. The etime is of type int (Example: 1532609527000) but looks like date is of format:

```
|java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,areAllFieldsSet=false,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="US/Pacific-New",offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=185,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=US/Pacific-New,offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=?,YEAR=2018,MONTH=6,WEEK_OF_YEAR=?,WEEK_OF_MONTH=?,DAY_OF_MONTH=26,DAY_OF_YEAR=?,DAY_OF_WEEK=?,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=?,AM_PM=0,HOUR=5,HOUR_OF_DAY=5,MINUTE=52,SECOND=7,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=?,DST_OFFSET=?]
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried printing the value of `date` to debug?

Comment: date.hour and date.minute gives me the right values. But I can't get it to this format datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 26, 8, 00, 00) . Methods like timestamp and fromtimestamp don't work on date

Answer (score 1):

the unixtype timestamp is the time passed in seconds from date 1970 Jan 01. so, you have to to convert the etime to normal format or convert the comparing date to unixtimestamp. Here is how you convert the unix time stamp to normal year,month,day,hhmmss format.
Hope this helps..

```
def unixtodate(utime):
  import datetime
  current=datetime.datetime(1970,01,01,00,00,00)+datetime.timedelta(seconds=utime)
  current=current.isoformat()
  return current
```

Comment: @noname please post whether this helped